# Avoid having to recompile after manually editing IDs in resource.h

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

If I manually edit IDs in the "resource.h" file of my Visual Studio 2005 project, I have to recompile the entire solution or the program will crash when running.

Recompilation is very slow, so I would like to know if there is a way to avoid it.

Comment: don't include resource.h everywhere and it won't cause a cascading rebuild

Comment: Typically, the `CWinApp` derived header file (`myproject.h`) is included in every source file and this header includes `resource.h`, causing most files to be recompiled. The trick is to remove `resource.h` from the project header and include it manually only in those files which directly reference resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-compile any file that uses any of those IDs. If things are setup correctly, changing that file should cause any file that includes it (either directly or indirectly) to recompile.

That may well be the whole program, and YES it's necessary.

Comment: Re-compile files that use those IDs is enough. But if I use 'ctrl+F7' to compile those files it won't work. IDE will skip it and tell you "Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)", so manaully change these file is necessary. Thanks.